# Making Rcout output appear on the R console immediately

Tags: r, flush, rcpp

I have coded an MCMC sampler using `Rcpp` (specifically, `RcppArmadillo`). I would like my sampler to print periodic status messages to the R console, but the messages appear all at once when the sampler terminates. The output statement is :

```
Rcout << "Progress => " 
      << double(iterations) / double(maxit) * 100 
      << "%" 
      << std::endl;
```

Can this code be augmented so that its output appears on the R console immediately?

R version: 2.14.1

platform: Darwin 9.8.0

Rcpp version: 0.9.10

Comment: You might need to flush the console output buffer. In c++ that's std::flush, perhaps there is an Rcpp equivalent?

Comment: Perhaps calling `R_FlushConsole` will do it

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour has been implemented in `Rcpp` 0.10.0 (to be released soon) following advice from [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329812/custom-flush-implementation).

In the meantime, you can manually call [`R_FlushConsole`](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Embedding-R-under-Unix_002dalikes)

Comment: While I was there. I implemented `Rcerr`

Comment: Neither std::flush nor R_FlushConsole fixes the problem. Outputting is still delayed until the function terminates.

Comment: thanks for the report. how do you run R ? On OSX's console ? with the standard R app ?

Comment: I use the standard app (R GUI version 1.43).

Comment: In R-devel's code, I can read: `This should have been fixed a long time ago .... Finally in Sep 2012 R.app sets ptr_R_FlushConsole` . Perhaps this works with R-devel.

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version of R, but the problem remains.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure this has been fixed on R 2.15.2 or in R-devel (2.16.0 to be). Which one did you install ? R-devel is available from here: http://r.research.att.com/

Answer (score 0):

flush() and flush.console() are still broken.  R 3.0.2 / OSX

Answer (score 0):

You need a hat trick:

```
R_FlushConsole();
R_ProcessEvents();
R_CheckUserInterrupt();
```

Copied from: [parallel-computing-in-r-with-c-within-r-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020228)