# Custom flush implementation

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to follow the logic of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243696/correctly-over-loading-a-stringbuf-to-replace-cout-in-a-matlab-mex-file) to create a custom `streambuf` in [`Rcpp`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html). Someone contributed the basic behaviour that allows us to write things like

```
Rcout << "some text" ;
```

where we implemented `xsputn` and `overflow` to redirect to `Rprintf` function.

```
std::streamsize Rcpp::Rstreambuf::xsputn(const char *s, std::streamsize num ) {
    Rprintf( "%.*s", num, s );
    return num;
}

int Rcpp::Rstreambuf::overflow(int c ) {
    if (c != EOF) {
        Rprintf( "%.1s", &c );
    }
    return c;
}
```

I would like to implement flushing too, i.e. support this syntax:

```
Rcout << "some text" << std::flush ;
```

Which method do I need to implement so that the `flush` manipulator works on my custom stream ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `sync()` function (like in [filebuf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/sync)):

```
protected:
virtual int sync()
```

Base version of [base_streambuf<>::sync()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsync) does nothing, one must overwrite it to make some synchronization with underlying stream.

Comment: Thanks. Implemented in svn revision 3935 of `Rcpp`